# This is a very simple MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

```
insert into teacher(name, password, gender, bloodgrp, email, branch, dob, medical, no, fno, mno, lno, frno, rollno, aid) 
values("sam", "sam", "male","opositive", "sa@gl.com", "anime", "28\7\99", "nothing", 1234576, 789065,  34567, 23456, 12398, 3, 3);
```

When I use it I get:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'bloodgrp' in 'field list'

So why exactly am I getting the error?

Structure of table:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| password | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gender   | varchar(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email    | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| branch   | varchar(5)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dob      | int(9)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| medical  | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| no       | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| fno      | int(10)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| mno      | int(10)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| lno      | int(10)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| frno     | int(10)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| rollno   | int(10)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| aid      | int(10)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| bloodgrp | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Do you have any triggers on this table? And can you add the output of a show create to the question as text please.

Comment: Note that password and no are keywords (which will not cause a problem) but I would avoid using them as column names.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code does not generate an error and here's the proof

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(name         varchar(20) ,                    
password     varchar(10)  ,                   
gender       varchar(6)   ,                   
email        varchar(15)  ,                   
branch       varchar(5)   ,                   
dob          int(9)       ,                   
medical      varchar(30)  ,                   
no           int(10)     , 
fno          int(10)     ,                 
mno         int(10)      ,                
lno         int(10)      ,                
frno        int(10)      ,                
rollno      int(10)      ,                
aid         int(10)      ,                
bloodgrp  varchar(15) 
);

insert into t
(name, password, gender, bloodgrp, email, branch, dob, medical, no, fno, mno, lno, frno, rollno, aid) 
values("sam", "sam", "male","opositive", "sa@gl.com", "anime", "28\7\99", "nothing", 1234576, 789065,  34567, 23456, 12398, 3, 3);
;

select * from t;
+------+----------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+---------+---------+--------+-------+-------+-------+--------+------+-----------+
| name | password | gender | email     | branch | dob   | medical | no      | fno    | mno   | lno   | frno  | rollno | aid  | bloodgrp  |
+------+----------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+---------+---------+--------+-------+-------+-------+--------+------+-----------+
| sam  | sam      | male   | sa@gl.com | anime  | 28799 | nothing | 1234576 | 789065 | 34567 | 23456 | 12398 |      3 |    3 | opositive |
+------+----------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+---------+---------+--------+-------+-------+-------+--------+------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

You may have a trigger on the table which is throwing the error or the error is not coming from the posted insert.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to call columns in order:

```
insert into teacher(name, password, gender, email, branch, dob, medical, no, fno, mno, lno, frno, rollno, aid, bloodgrp) 
values("sam", "sam", "male", "sa@gl.com", "anime", "28\7\99", "nothing", 1234576, 789065,  34567, 23456, 12398, 3, 3,"opositive");
```

Also look at `dob`, you defined it datatype as `int(9)` and you try to put here `varchar` -> `"28\7\99"`. It could make a new issue for you.

Why you've defined this column `bloodgrp` with `NULL` -> `NO` and in the same time `DEFAULT` -> `NULL`?

Comment: The columns do not need to be in the same order as they are defined in the CREATE statement.

Comment: 'Because you need to call columns in order:' not true.

Comment: in his case it seems to be in order. Wrong datatype rising another error message.